# Можно ли повторно установить Bitrix шаблон

Tags: битрикс

Ранее (около 4 лет назад я покупал шаблон от орпсА (замаскировал, чтобы не было рекламы). Шаблон нормальный, установил тогда на сайт и всё ок. Но сейчас мне нужно сделать сайт на Битрикс снова. В связи и с чем возник вопрос - могу ли я купить отдельно движок Битрикс и скопировать все файлы со старого сайта на новый хостинг? Можно ли будет таким образом скопировать свой первый сайт? Не сочтите меня за негодяя, просто платить снова деньги за точно такой же шаблон жаба душит, по сему и спрашиваю, можно ли так или нет...
Скажите пожалуйста, будет ли новый сайт полностью повторять старый сайт (меню, админка и прочее)? Какие подводные камни здесь есть? Не будет ли каких-либо глюков?
Буду втройне благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, в каких папках интересуют меня файлы...
Заранее благодарю и очень надеюсь на вашу помощь и на то, что я смогу сэкономить!)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно условий лицензии, то так делать нельзя, вы можите купить продление лицензии битрикс. Потом обновить ядро(и если не будет ошибок - вам повезло) и тогда у вас снимут ограничение на количество сайтов на одном ядре. после этого на томже ядре но с тругим доменом можно сделать точную копию сайта.

а теперь если наплевать на лицензионные условия, то просто заходите в Настройки->Резрвное копирование и создаете полный бекап всего сайта и потом с помощью файла востановления востановите полную копию на другом сервере
вот инструкция https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=32&CHAPTER_ID=02014&LESSON_PATH=3903.4862.4894.2014